# Как выдрать данные из видео?

Tags: php

Нужно достать тех. данные из списка видео файлов разных форматов. Как/чем?
Можно не для всех форматов, а хотя бы для wmv, avi, mpg.

Comment: Под линуксом?

Comment: ты можеш попробовать PrintScreen
потом распознать тех

Comment: Ответ в общем виде - ищите описание форматов и разбирайте в соответствии с ними. <a href="http://rfteam.110mb.com/revers/5.php">Структура AVI</a>, например. Но, конечно, это не ответ)

Answer (score 2):

Есть расширение для php: ffmpeg. По [ссылке](http://pyha.ru/forum/topic/1317.0) можно почитать примерный перевод API.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg - i sample.avi
```

Выдаст много текста, в том числе содержащего, например, такое

> `Duration: 00:02:38.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 256 kb/s`
> `Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 256 kb/s`

Распарсить для получения нужных данных можно регулярными выражениями.